# Multiple dots/periods in CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css-selectors

Can one of you CSS experts explain this designator (if that's even what you'd call it) to me? I understand the contents, just not the a.button.gold.  Two dots?

```
a.button.gold{
background-color: #b9972f;
}
```

I am trying to modify a couple of styles on a Wordpress theme and would have a lot more success with it, if I could figure out what is currently happening.
Thanks

Comment: Any anchor tag that has the class `button` that has the class `gold`

Comment: Its a `link` with a `button` having class `gold`?

Comment: a .button .gold{ background-color: #b9972f;
}Now its better. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The selector simply means select any `a` element having class `.button` AS WELL AS `.gold` so your anchor tag should look like

```
<a href="#" class="button gold">Hello</a>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GAK5q/)

The selector can be also written as `element[attr~=val]` as @BoltClock Commented like

```
a[class~="button"][class~="gold"] {
   color: #f00;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GAK5q/4/)

---

Generally the above(Not the selector, but calling multiple classes for a single element method) is also used when you want to apply properties of 2 classes to a single element, so say for example you have `.demo` having `color: green;` and `.demo2` having `font-weight: bold;` so using

```
<p class="demo demo2">Hello, this will be green as well as bold</p>
```

Will make it green as well as bold. [**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/GAK5q/1/)

Comment: The selector `a[class="button gold"]` is not equivalent to `a.button.gold`. The latter matches e.g. `<a class="gold button">...</a>` and `<a class="button gold foo">...</a>`, the former does not.

Comment: A more accurate use of attribute selectors would be `a[class~="button"][class~="gold"]`. Your edit does not address `<a class="gold button">`.

Comment: @BoltClock I forgot the ordering issue here, thanks for that, will edit my answer..

Comment: Thank you for laying it out so explicitly.  Makes sense now.

Answer (score 3):

This selector represents an `<a>` element with two classes, as you can have as many classes (separated with a white-space in the class attribute itself) in CSS as you'd like. The HTML would look like:

```
<a href="#" class="button gold">Test</a>
```

If the `<a>` had three classes you'd just continue the pattern:

```
<a href="#" class="button gold test">Test</a>

a.button.gold.test {
    color: peachpuff;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NeqAg/

Comment: Does `.button.gold` mean the element must have `button` AND `gold` exactly or at least `button` AND `gold`?